# Is it possible to provide USERPRINCIPALNAME in a Calculated Column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement in my project where I have to concatenate the e-mail ID of the report user in a column.

The Column where this has to be done is a web-link that redirects to a different application.

So for eg: the data in the columns is "**[www.abc.html?/powerbi**"](http://www.abc.html?/powerbi**%22).
My result should be "**[www.abc.html?/powerbi,emailid@company.com**"](http://www.abc.html?/powerbi,emailid@company.com**%22)

I want to get the email id of the user who is accessing he report.

I am not able to use USERPRINCIPALNAME() in calculated columns. Is there any alternate way to achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 2):

Columns are created at refresh time, and it would not make sense to include things like `USERPRINCIPALNAME` in a column.

Measures are calculated at query time, and can contain these things. You could try to incorporate this in a measure instead.

Comment: Hello Marcus,

Thanks for the reply :-). But I don't think I will be able to do this in a measure.
Because when I create the link in calculated column, I am merging few Column data to the link as well, and this can't be done in a measure. And along with that link I also need to provide the mail id of the person who is using the report. So I was trying to do this in a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the value of userprincipal() into a text field with a DAX query in a measure. An example of this is below:

```
WebUrl = www.abc.html?/powerbi,"&Userprincipal()&"/somefolder/"&FirstNonBlank(Table[ConcatText],Table[ConcatText]=Table[ConcatText])
```

If you need it with specific text from another field, you can force the text from the line by adding formula like FirstNonBlank() as below:

```
WebUrl2 = www.abc.html?/powerbi,"&Userprincipal()&FirstNonBlank(Table[TableName],TableName[Text]=TableName[Text])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).